# Select all elements with onClick listener (js function) added to them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to select all html elements who have a javascript function added as listener to onClick.

I can select them if they have added **onclick** as an attribute in html
with `$("[onclick]")`, but the listener can be added later with javascript.

Is it possible to select all elements regardless how the listener was added? Return both elements in the example.

```js
(function(){ 
function modify() {
  alert('inca un salut');
}
var t2 = document.getElementById("button2");
t2.addEventListener("click", modify, false);
console.log($("[onclick]"));
}())
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" id="button1" onclick="alert('salut')" value="click here" />

<input type="button" id="button2" value="click here element 2" />
```

Or Jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/alexrada/dpbgw6yk/3/

Comment: why not have your function put all the elements with the attribute `onClick` into an array and then alert those. That way each time you click, you will recheck the HTML for element with `onClick` and populate the array.

Comment: because my .js will run on other website, which I can't control

Comment: what do you mean ? Your javascript will be crawling another website for these elements?

Comment: you can say crawling. It's a service installed on another websites.

Answer (score 2):

It actually depends on how the events are attached to the dom element in javascript. It can be added using jQuery or other library or pure javascript as well.

If you want to know how it can be done if the events are attached using jQuery then you can do something like this.

```
var clickEvents = $(element).data("events").click;
$.each(clickEvents, function(key, event) {
    alert(event.handler)
});
```

So along with inline `onclick` event handler and the events attached through javascript will give you the total number of event handler on that dom element.

I think we cannot inspect event handlers attached with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent(IE specific)`

**Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/onzof2eL/

If you are using higher version of jQuery then you have to use `$._data(element, "events")` like @Frogmouth mentioned in the comment below.

Comment: `$(element).data(“events”)` is deprecated since version `1.8` use `$._data(element, "events")` instead.

Comment: @wolff - I think we cannot inspect event handlers attached with `addEventListener` or `attachEvent(IE specific)`